# How to get unique record?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, group-by

I get an output records like below by using join from different tables

```
key   init_amt   get_amt  pct
-------------------------------
12      234        150     30
13      56         45       0
15      996        100      0
12      234        150     30
57      45         20       0
33      123        98      30
15      567        400     30
```

Below is the query i made to get the output like above

```
SELECT key, SUM(init_amt), SUM(get_amt), MAX(get_amt), pct
(SELECT key, init_amt, get_amt, pct
 FROM amount mt INNER JOIN pct pc
 ON mt.key = pc.int_key)
 GROUP BY key
```

I want unique records like `key = 15, 33 ...so on` But the problem is i gwtting duplicate record also like `key = 12`. How can i achieve this.

`note: Query am gave above should not be completely change, we can make changes only becz it a dito of live`

Comment: Your query wouldn't run and it is difficult to see how it would generate the posted output. (Why are the values for `key=12` the same but the values for `key=15` different?)  You need to give us a reproducible test case, including sample input data for both tables and expected output derived from that sample.

Comment: Your post is inconsistent. The output you get was not produced by the query you posted. Even if you correct,it will not produce the give output. Your output shows 4 columns, the query selects 5.  Looks like the results you posted come from just the sub-query. Please review [ask], then repost your question.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, your query would error, because `pct` is not an aggregate column and is not part of the `group by` clause. If you want a unique record per `key`, then use an aggregate functions on `pct`, for example:

```
SELECT key, SUM(init_amt), SUM(get_amt), MAX(get_amt), MAX(pct)
FROM (...)
GROUP BY key
```

Answer (score -1):

Add distinct after select

```
SELECT distinct key, SUM(init_amt), SUM(get_amt), MAX(get_amt), pct
(SELECT key, init_amt, get_amt, pct
 FROM amount mt INNER JOIN pct pc
 ON mt.key = pc.int_key)
 GROUP BY key
```

Comment: DISTINCT won't do anything along with GROUP BY, so ... that's pretty much irrelevant.

Comment: Write an outer select query with distinct. It'll work